# JavaScript, output in calculator

Tags: javascript, html, output, calculator

I have a problem with my very simple calculator in JS. 
I want it to show the result in a box but I don't know what it is that I'm doing wrong. 
There is probably some more things in my code that might not be right...
Please help me!

Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('submit').onclick=function() {
 num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valueA').value);
 num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valueB').value);
 arithmeticOperator = document.getElementById('arithmeticOperator').value;
 
 switch(arithmeticOperator) {
  case '+':
   result = num1 + num2;
   break;
  case '-':
   result = num1 - num2;
   break;
  case '*':
   result = num1 * num2;
   break;
  case '/':
   if(num2 != 0)
   {
    result = num1 / num2;
   }else {
    result = 'Dela inte med 0!';
   }
   break;
  default:
   result = 'Error';
 }
 document.getElementById('calcForm').onclick=output;
window.alert('result');
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>blabla</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="js.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="calcForm" id="calcForm">
  <p><input type="number" name="valueA" placeholder="Värde A" /></p>
  <p><input type="number" name="valueB" placeholder="Värde B" /></p>

  <select name="arithmeticOperator">
   <option value="+">Addition</option>
   <option value="-">Subtraktion</option>
   <option value="/">Division</option>
   <option value="*">Multiplication</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Räkna ut</button>
  
  <p><output name="result" form="calcForm"></output></p>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

:)

Comment: `document.getElementById` is used with element ids, look how you using it.

Comment: your `window.alert('result');` will not display the exact result, as your calling that in single quote.

Answer (score 2):

- First you have no element with the id of submit.
- You are trying to add onclick handler to the element before it exists.
- You are selecting other elements with id, but they only have a name.
- You are adding a click event to a form, not sure what you expect that to do when there is no method output.

Comment: Can you please show me what to do? Or tell me a bit more.

Comment: Check my answer for the full code. Although, you should be trying yourself to fix your own code based on the good advice received here.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting by `id`, but the value `arithmeticOperator` is the `name` of your select box.

Try this:
`<select name="arithmeticOperator" id="arithmeticOperator">`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` gets elements by their `id`. You have multiple cases where you're trying to find elements with their name or type. That won't work.

`document.getElementById('calcForm').onclick=output;`
This tries to bind a function called output to the click event of an element called calcForm. I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

To show the result in an input or output, you can just do
`document.getElementById("idOfTheElement").value = result;`

Answer (score 0):

As you seem eager to just know the solution - I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9d0wx1r/1/) for you.

**Please** go over it carefully and check the edits I've done in your code.

Numerous errors, typos changed (as mentioned by others) include:

- Every `name=` instance can be swapped out by `id=` in your code.. It's crucial in javascript to understand the difference.
- You didn't declare any of the variables at the start. Any javascript variable starts with `var` (including arrays, objects and often even functions)
- The code was giving a POST error. You have to handle the submit event of a form (because HTML automatically wants to send it) - see the first line in the function `event.preventDefault()`

The javascript code reworked:

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valueA').value),
        num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valueB').value),
        arithmeticOperator = document.getElementById('arithmeticOperator').value,
        output = document.getElementById('result');

    switch(arithmeticOperator) {
        case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
            break;
        case '/':
            if(num2 != 0)
            {
                result = num1 / num2;
            }else {
                result = 'Dela inte med 0!';
            }
            break;
        default:
            result = 'Error';
    }
    output.innerHTML = result;
    window.alert(result);
    return false;
};
```

And the HTML with some modifications:

```
<form name="calcForm" id="calcForm">
    <p><input type="number" id="valueA" placeholder="Värde A" /></p>
    <p><input type="number" id="valueB" placeholder="Värde B" /></p>

    <select name="arithmeticOperator" id="arithmeticOperator">
        <option value="+">Addition</option>
        <option value="-">Subtraktion</option>
        <option value="/">Division</option>
        <option value="*">Multiplication</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Räkna ut</button>

    <p>Result: <output id="result" form="calcForm"></output></p>
</form>
```